# Assigning the Value of textfield which is string to char*

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, char

In my project, if I do this

```
char *string =@"hello";
```

it works properly. But when I enter something in a `UITextField` and assign that to `char`, it is not showing the proper value.

Even if i declare

```
 NSString *string ;
 self.stringVariable = mobileNumberTextField.text;
 char * mobile = string;
 char *c[]= {Enc,Mac,Mobile};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using conversion:

When you get the string value from the textfield to your char:

```
const char *myCharString = [your_textField.text UTF8String];
```

and use that char as you need.

and viceversa, when you wanna display that char back into the textField:

```
[your_textField setText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:myCharString]];
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

NSString is an Objective-C object, whereas char pointer is just a plain C pointer type. You can't use them interchangeably or you'll experience runtime errors (most likely segfaults). You have to create a char pointer from an NSString (and also the other way around);

```
const char *str = "Something as a C string";
NSString *nsStr = [NSString stringWithCStrint:str encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // or ASCII
```